# Build-time assembly of HTML and JS fragments for Single-page applications

Tags: javascript, html, build, singlepage

I'm preparing to write a large single-page app but I'm looking for a better way to develop it than writing the whole thing as a single file. I'm concerned about maintainability and testibility so I'd prefer to split it up into modules or fragments which can be developed and tested separately, then assembled into a single file at build-time. I don't believe I'll need to do any server-side templating so the final file delivered to the browser will be static and any customization done via JavaScript in the browser.

What I *think* I'd also like (but perhaps tools with better methods exist but I just haven't found them yet) is to develop the HTML fragments within full, self-contained HTML files so that they can be tested as standalone pages without having to assemble the entire app. This means there would need to be a way to tell the assembly tool which part of a fragment file is the actual fragment so that it should discard the HTML sandbox surrounding it.

Are there any development tools which would enable me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are planning to build a modular application am i right? then take a look at these resources:

- [Nicholas Zakas' scalable, modular JavaScript](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXjVFPosQHw) - this one discusses the "take apart and individually testable" part you are looking for
- [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) for inter-JS dependency handling - for JS files that need other JS files to work
- [BackboneJS](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) - for structuring your application
- [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) template builder - to avoid writing your HTML in JS files
- an multi-purpose toolkit like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)